# issue with Docker registry having ngnix authentication

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have installed my private docker registry with ngnix HTTP authentication where registry is running on port 5000 and ngnix on 8000. I am able to login to the registry after creating credentials. But hitting with the strange issue which is not allowing me to pull and push any image to that. Would be very helpful if you can give pointers on the same. The error message I get is :

FATA[0000] HTTP code 401, Docker will not send auth headers over HTTP.

Thanks in advance,

~Yash

Comment: This [issue discussion](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues) and [especially this comment](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/541#issuecomment-56577919) may help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, I am only using HTTP and have not set up SSL. Can we not connect to docker-registry with only nginx HTTP authentication without setting up any SSL?

Comment: Docker itself doesn't support this. From the linked thread: "[As advertised in the past](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/298#issuecomment-39845868), we do not support authentication over HTTP. If docker tries to send credentials over HTTP, then it is a bug and it needs to be fixed, but very clearly we have no intention to support non-HTTPS auth."

Comment: You probably can authenticate requests using NginX and then pass them to Docker registry, removing all auth headers, but I doubt that Docker client will work that way. [From the same thread](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/541#issuecomment-55586491): "If docker-registry run over HTTP, docker sends Basic Authorization headers with the first request and after that switches to Token Authorization."

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, It clears my doubts :) but when you say "removing all auth headers" means what? where we can configure that? excuse me for this as I am very novice in this area. Would be great if you can tell where to do this. I would want this to give a trial.

Comment: You can remove auth headers [in NginX config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) and run Docker registry in the [standalone mode](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry#authentication-options). But I'm not sure it will help, because Docker client, when used over HTTP, switches to token auth after the very first request. This will prevent NginX from authenticating all subsequent HTTP requests. See the issue I linked for more details.